# Prove $\lim_{x \to -1} \dfrac{x+5}{2x+3} = 4 $

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove $\lim_{x \to -1} \dfrac{x+5}{2x+3} = 4 $

I need to find a lower bound for $|2x+3|$ in order to prove this but I can't see the way, as I always ended up with upper bounds.

Comment: Well, $0$ is always a lower bound of $|2x+3|$.  But note we are taking $x$ "very close" to $-1$ so $2x+3$ is "very close to $2(-1)+3$ so by taking $\delta$ small enough we can get $2x+3 > 0$ and $2x+3 > l > 0$ for any $l: 0 < l < 1$.  To formalize: $|x-(-1)|=|x+1| < \delta \implies -\delta < x+1< \delta\implies -1-\delta < x< -1+\delta\implies -2-2\delta < 2x< -2+2\delta\implies 1-2\delta < 2x+3 <1+2\delta$. For any $l:0<l<1$ we can get $0<l<1-2\delta<2x+3$ be chosing any $\delta:\delta < \frac {1-l}2$. We can have $\frac 12$ as a lower limit by $\delta < \frac 14$ for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $|2x+3|=|2(x+1)+1|\geq 1-2|x+1|>1-2\delta$ if $|x+1| <\delta$.

Comment: How's this inequality formed? I didn't get that

Comment: "Reverse triangle inequlity": $|a+b| \geq |a|-|b|$. This follows from triangle inequality: $|a|=|(a+b)+(-b)| \leq |a+b| +|b|$. Take $|b|$ to the left side. @Lucifer

Comment: Isn't it $|a-b| \geq | |a| - |b| | $

Comment: @Lucifer What you have writen is stronger than what I used! Recall that $|y| \geq y$ always. So $||a|-|b|| \geq |a|-|b|$.

Comment: Thank you so much got it